# PHP / MySQL Forum Post Order

Tags: php, mysql, forum

I have one table called `cf_posts`

```
ID pk
user INT
subject VARCHAR
body TEXT
datetime TIMESTAMP
parent INT
category INT
mod INT
```

When a post is submitted to the forum the default parent is 0, when a post is submitted as a reply, then its parent is the ID of the original post.

How can I make it so that the default view of the forum main page is ordered that the most recently updated post (including the latest replies) would be at the "top" of the pile, and working down in date order?  What would be the PHP/MySQL query?

The only workarounds I have seen for this are separate topics and reply tables, but I'd like to stay away from this approach if possible.

One workaround that I tried and failed was GROUP BY parent.
But this grouped all topics that had no replies together as one.

Another idea that I have yet to try is to make the parent id of the original post match the post ID, and not include matching ID and parent IDs in the output.

I look forward to hearing your thoughts.

Comment: What is your reason to stay away from separate topics and replies tables?

Comment: @Raidenace A topic is just a special post, no reason to create a separate table.

Comment: You can tell if it's a topic because it will have no parent presumably? (Matt?)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mainPost.subject, lastPost.datetime
FROM cf_posts cfp, 
(
 SELECT * 
 FROM cf_posts subPost
 WHERE subPost.parent = mainPost
 ORDER BY subPost.datetime DESC
 LIMIT 1
)lastPost
WHERE mainPost.parent IS NULL
```

This is done briefly, so there may be some syntax issues but I think this should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following: query each separate thing that you need, so maybe a query for each topic, Then you can use UNION to bunch all of them together to get one list. Now the trick to preserve an order is as followed. For each separate query append a column to the returned result called sort and set each instance of that to a higher int value, then you can guarantee that the final result is properly sorted. Go review UNION for select statements to get a better understanding of what I'm talking about.